# Is memsup:get_system_memory_data reporting weird numbers or am I mis-interpreting them?

Tags: macos, memory, erlang

I'm brand new to Erlang and have recently discovered the `os_mon` application. For reference I'm on OS X 10.7 and using Erlang R16B02.

Basically, when I run `memsup:get_system_memory_data()`, I'm getting numbers like these:

```
[{total_memory,7410088000},
  {free_memory,1758936000},
  {system_total_memory,7410088000}]
```

A little bit of division tells me this means I've only got 23% free memory which seems like it can't be right. Running the same function inside an erlang shell not associated with my application gives me the same thing. I assume that number can't be right because Activity Monitor is currently telling me this:

```
Out of 8.00 GB

Free: 2.6 GB
Wired: 1.16 GB
Active: 3.23 GB
Inactive: 1,012.6 MB
Used: 5.39 GB
```

So there's at least 32% reported purely as free. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is a bug** in Erlang, and more precisely in [memsup.erl](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/os_mon/src/memsup.erl#L724). You will see that there is a comment in the code about MacOS X 10.2.2. Pages are probably 4096 bytes now.

The page size does not explain the ratio you get, though. According to the following question, one should add the number of `Pages speculative` to get the total number of free pages.

https://superuser.com/questions/197059/mac-os-x-sysctl-get-total-and-free-memory-size

Please do not hesitate to [file a patch](https://github.com/erlang/otp/wiki/Submitting-patches).